# How do you change the first page that's shown when you click on a GitHub repo?

Tags: github

Github default to the readme.md file. How can I change the default page to be a Jupyter notebook (.ipynb) file?

Answer (score 2):

You can not, until unless github introduces this option, which is not available currently. As per their [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/) -

> The contents of your README file are automatically shown on the front page of your repository.